# New to SQL Regression but have done regression with SPSS and SYSTAT

Tags: sql, regression, spss

I have never preformed regression with SQL and I am kind of confused on how it works. I have a table with a rating amount and 36 elements, so the dependent would be the Rate and the independents would be the 36 elements. How is this done in SQL 2008R2? I have worked with SPSS and SYSTAT but we want a more automated system of doing this.

thank you!
Not homework!

Answer (score 0):

What would not be automated using SPSS or SYSTAT?

Answer (score 0):

I did end up using SPSS, I added the .net connector to it and now can query SQL right in to SPSS.